# Recover the ids of updated rows

Tags: qt, sql-update, qsqlquery

I need to be able to recover the ids of the rows updated by an UPDATE query using the QSqlQuery class of Qt.

I don't know if it is even possible, but there is a similar mecanism which allows to recover the id of the last row inserted by a QSqlQuery: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId

If anyone can give me a way to do that or to ensure me that it is not possible, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Using PostgreSQL (not available with SqlServer):

```
QSqlQuery query("UPDATE myTable SET value=1 WHERE value=0 RETURNING id");
while (query.next()) {
  int id = query.value(0).toInt();
  qDebug() << id;
}
```